# Firebase Crashlytics Build Secret for Fastlane

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, fastlane

I'm attempting to use Fastlane to automate an Android build, including Crashlytics.

My Fastfile includes:

```
  lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    crashlytics(api_token: "my-token")
    upload_to_play_store(track: "internal")
  end
```

When I invoke `fastlane deploy`, it stops at the Crashlytics step and prompts:

```
    [06:57:27]: -------------------------
    [06:57:27]: --- Step: crashlytics ---
    [06:57:27]: -------------------------
    [06:57:27]: To not be asked about this value, you         can specify it using 'build_secret'
    [06:57:27]: Crashlytics Build Secret:
```

I'm trying to figure out where to get the build secret from the Firebase Crashlytics console. I don't see it there.

Where do I find the build secret for Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: Hey man! Trying the same thing. Did you manage to find out the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Firebase here. If you're still using Beta, then you need to set that up via Fabric. You can get your [Build Secret](https://www.fabric.io/settings/organizations) by accessing your organization's settings page within Fabric and click on the link under the organization's name.

Comment: This makes no sense. I don't even know what fabric is. I've been exclusively in Firebase. Any help would be appreciated.. No sign of the word beta anywhere

Comment: @bryan if you need specific help, I'd recommend reaching out to Firebase's support team. If you're hitting this issue while using Firebase exclusively, then getting the specifics of your setup will be needed to solve the issue.